# Removing/Hiding the Tomcat version on error pages

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, iis, custom-error-pages

I am currently having difficulties removing/ hiding the Tomcat version on my error page.

All the methods and steps that I have tried do not work, I have run through multiple solutions and checked each step accordingly. However, to no avail.. none of them works. Below is a list of what I have tried. I appreciate any tips/ suggestions. Thank you!

1. Added a valve statement to the server.xml.

```html
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" />
```

2. Created a ServerInfo.properties file in /lib/org/apache/catalina/util

   server.info= Test
3. Modified the web.xml file with the following code and HTML files.

```html
  <error-page>
   <error-code>500</error-code>
   <location>/errors/500.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/errors/404.html</location>
  </error-page>
```

4.Redirecting the error by using httpsError in the web.config file
Here is the code and error that I got. (HTTP Error 500.19, error code 0x8007000d)
And I have URL Rewrite installed. Sorry for the horrible images, I wasn't able to take a snippet.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt5kp.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfkaa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**:

This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed or unidentified XML element. IIS can't identify the XML elements of the modules that are not installed. For example, IIS URL Rewrite module.

**Resolution**:

Use one of the following methods:

- Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config or
  Web.config file.
- Check the unidentified XML elements, and then install the relevant
  IIS modules.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, I played around and realised that my web.config file was pointing to the wrong directory. However, a new error came out. It now shows the Error 404.0 and the Error Code 0x80070002 on the local server. But it is able to load the error page that I want on another local server... so the local server that contains the web.config is currently facing this error.

Comment: Try to change the Application Pool from Classic to Integrated.